# Unable to use Quicksight dashboard as embeded url on S3/cloudfront whitelisted domain

Tags: amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I was trying to view Quicksight dashboard as embedded url from our domain which was whitelisted in AWS Quicksight account.
Our website is hosted on S3 bucket as a static website. Below sample, a javascript function is given on an [AWS Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-interactive-dashboards-in-your-application-with-amazon-quicksight/).

Below is the sample javascript function.

```
function embedDashboard() {
                var containerDiv = document.getElementById("dashboardContainer");
                var options = {
                    url: "<signed URL from Step 3>",
                    container: containerDiv,
                    parameters: {
                        country: 'United States'
                    },
                    scrolling: "no",
                    height: "700px",
                    width: "1000px"
                };
                dashboard = QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard(options);
                dashboard.on('error', onError);
                dashboard.on('load', onDashboardLoad);
            }
```

Full example is given on another link of the same blog [Amazon QuickSight JavaScript SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk)

Unfortunately, the sample is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a complete html sample page (dashboard.html), including the javascript function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Dashboard</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="quicksight-embedding-js-sdk.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function embedDashboard() {
                var containerDiv = document.getElementById("dashboardContainer");
                var params = {
                    url: "<signed URL>",
                    container: containerDiv,
                    parameters: {
                    },
                    height: "700px",
                    width: "1000px"
                };
                var dashboard = QuickSightEmbedding.embedDashboard(params);
                dashboard.on('error', function(err) {console.log('dashboard error:', err)});
                dashboard.on('load', function() {});
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="embedDashboard()">
        <div id="dashboardContainer"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Sample is taken from same AWS blog and made some changes.

Overall steps are summarized below.

**Below line was changed.**
[image]
Above line was changed with below line.
[image]
**Downloaded .js and lib files**

Some .js and lib files were also downloaded from below address and uploaded on the website with the dashboard.html page.

https://unpkg.com/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk@1.0.2/dist/
[image]
**S3/Cloudfront configuration**

Since whitelisted domain on quicksight setting is an https url, so had to configure s3 static website with Cloudfront.

--created s3 bucket with dashboard.mydomain.com.au

--created Cloudfront web distribution including SSL from ACM.

--created A Record / Alias in Route53 with Cloudfront dns entry.

**Generated dashboard-embed-url**

AWS CLI command

```
aws quicksight get-dashboard-embed-url --aws-account-id 00000000000 --dashboard-id "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx" --identity-type "IAM"
```

**Used this Embedded / signed Url in dashboard.html in "signed URL"**

Upload dashboard.html on s3 bucket.

**Webpage is ready**

Now webpage is available with quicksight dashboard from whitelisted domain.

```
https://dashboard.mydomain.com.au/dashboard.html
```